# NetBeans "Last Modified:" template

Tags: netbeans, phpdoc

Hopefully a simple question.

I've started using NetBeans for a new multi-developer PHP project I am working on. One thing I have noticed in scripts in the past is a section in the PHPDoc at the top with something similar to

```
/**
 * PDO Database Configuration
 * Last Updated: %Date: 15/03/2011, 22:31:04 GMT (Tue 15th Mar 2011)%
 *
 * @author      lethalMango
 ...
*/
```

Is there a method to get that "Last Updated:" section to update automatically on save?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Melv says, a common way of doing is via the version control system.  This is a better approach than relying on the IDE since it only needs setting up once server-side rather than on every client.

If you're using Subversion, you'd do this with [properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3).

Something like this, assuming `yourfile.php` has been added to svn:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "LastChangedDate" yourfile.php
```

Then add the string `$LastChangedDate$` to the file, and every time the file is committed the keyword will be expanded to include the date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Netbeans doesn't give you anything like that. I don't know of a plugin that gives you a hook to it either, but there are definitely ways of doing this sort of thing on versioning commits and/or in build tools, so that might be the best way to tackle it.

Comment: Great stuff thanks, any idea where to look for the types of build tools you mention?

Comment: @lethalMango [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) are the 2 popular ones for Java, unfortunately I'm not sure what's popular for PHP.